# Create site-to-site VPN from linux to Cisco - possible?

Tags: linux, vpn

I have a question that I have not found a definitive answer on, but am hoping someone here can chime in and either point me in the right direction or crush my hopes and dreams.

I have a Cisco ASA 5520 at an office. At a couple remote sites, there are linux boxes functioning as the network gateway/firewall. Is there a way to create a site-to-site VPN from one of those linux boxes to the ASA or will an investment in another ASA be required to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several OpenSource IPsec implementations that allow you to create site-to-site VPNs with Cisco ASA firewalls.

Among them are [strongSwan](http://www.strongswan.org) (I'm a developer for that project), [Openswan](http://www.openswan.org) and [racoon](http://ipsec-tools.sourceforge.net).

If the ASA is updated to a recent firmware ([at least ASA 8.4 seems to be required](https://supportforums.cisco.com/community/netpro/security/vpn/blog/2011/02/08/asa-84-ipsec-vpn--whats-new)) you should be able to use IKEv2 together with [strongSwan](http://www.strongswan.org), which makes configuration easier than when using IKEv1.

Comment: Those all appear to be what I am looking for! It appears I was not using good enough terminology to have these pop up in a Google search. Thanks for a quick response. I'll definitely post back once I get one up and working.